# Comparing 2 CSV files with different column names

Tags: csv, powershell

I have 2 csv files that look like the following:

**File 1:**

Ip Address, Setting

**File 2:**

Port IP (same as IP address with diff name), Name

What I want to do is take the IP address from File 1 and compare it to the port IP from File 2 and grab the Name.  I then want to create a 3rd file with the following:

QueName, IP Address, Setting

An IP from File 1 can have multiple IPs in File 2 (one IP can belong to multiple queues) so when I tried the following it would give me the list of all the IP address at once and I could not concatenate  the Setting field to all of the rows.

```
$duplexdata = Import-CSV "C:\queues\duplex.csv"
$countduplexdata = (Import-CSV "C:\queues\duplex.csv").count
$qip = Import-CSV "C:\queues\qip.csv"
$countqip = (Import-CSV "C:\queues\duplex.csv").count

$i=0
$j=0

for($i=0; $i -le $countduplexdata+1; $i++)
{
$ipaddress=$duplexdata.'IP address'[$i]
$qip | where{$_.PortIP -eq "$ipaddress"}
```

That gets the following data:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mCT4.jpg, which is fine but when I try to concatenate the setting field from File 1 it only adds it at the end of each chunk of data that it finds.  How can I add that value to each of the rows?

Comment: You should give an example of your CSV files if yiu want more accurate result.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over the output files you could easily change one of the "columns" after importing the file using a calculated property.

```
$duplexdata = Import-CSV "C:\queues\duplex.csv"
$qip = Import-CSV "C:\queues\qip.csv" | Select @{Label="Ip Address";Expression={$_.PortIP}}
```

So now both `$duplexdata` and `$qip` share a column call "Ip Address" without having to change the source file.

That doesn't really matter in this case though. What you are asking for is something like a SQL JOIN. I would suggest looking at this article for the [Join-Object](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/07/13/join-object.aspx). But you have a small data set so you could just do something like this.

```
$duplexdata = Import-CSV "C:\temp\file1.csv"
$qip = Import-CSV "C:\temp\file2.csv"

$qip | ForEach-Object{
    $address = $_."Port IP"
    New-Object -Typename psobject -Property @{
        "IP Address" = $address
        Setting = $duplexdata | Where-Object{$_."Ip Address" -eq $address} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Setting
        Name = $_.Name
    }
} | Select-Object "Ip Address",Name,Setting
```

Just makes a new object for every `$qip`. For each `$qip` we find the matching setting from the other files data.

---

Also I see you importing the file twice. First for data and second for count. It is redundant to do so.

```
$duplexdata = Import-CSV "C:\queues\duplex.csv"
$countduplexdata = (Import-CSV "C:\queues\duplex.csv").count
```

Could just be

```
$duplexdata = Import-CSV "C:\queues\duplex.csv"
$countduplexdata = $duplexdata.count
```

Answer (score -1):

I would try another approach :

First I would change the header of the CVS file to have a common column IP.

Second, I would add the two sets of objects.

```
$duplexdata = Import-CSV "C:\queues\duplex.csv"
$qip = Import-CSV "C:\queues\qip.csv"
$duplexdata,$qip | group-object -Property 'IP address'
```

Third in the result I find a group property with all the lines allowing me to build a new object.